# How do I save a photo including location from a shared album or even see the location?

Tags: google-photos

Google seems to be removing the location from all photos from others in shared albums. Is there any way to get this data back?

- I don't see the location in the web UI
- I downloaded the album from the web UI and `exiftool` doesn't show GPS data
- Google Takeout doesn't include shared photos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you can get your data back but whenever I had a picture from my old phone and my current new phone, the GPS data shared with the photo. Even my parents' pictures had their GPS location tagged with the photo. In Google Photos on your phone, select the picture and swipe up. It should give you information on the date the picture was taken and where it was taken.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. On second inspection, Google Photos actually does share GPS, but it looks like the photos actually didn't include GPS data when taken. All the photos in the shared album were taken by iPhones, so perhaps iPhone's default is to not include location data in the photo?